# How to reduce duplicate questions on a growing site?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I posted [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13148/what-jobs-can-wizards-and-witches-do) that has been repeatedly asked. I did try to search before I posted but on a site like this one where there is a long history of questions on the subject it was a bit too much to look through while I'm at work. So is there any way to better search through questions or is this even a problem that other people are having?

Comment: How/what DID you search? It's hard to answer "is there any way to **better** search" without knowing what you did.

Comment: I looked up the Harry Potter tag and searched through a few pages. Like I said there were to many for me to go through them all while at work. I also entered Harry Potter and work in the search and when I typed my question I searched through the suggestions of similar articles based on what question I was typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A certain rate of duplicate questions is to be expected. Duplicate questions are when humans are better than search engine at finding the question that was asked before. It happens. Duplicate questions that are differently worded are also an asset to the site, as they bring more search fodder to find the original answers.

This isn't to say you shouldn't search before asking, and check the “related questions” that appear when you type your question, but we do understand that sometimes you won't find the existing question because it was worded too differently.

See also [discussions about duplicates on the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates); Stack Overflow is so much bigger, its duplication problem is a lot worse.

Answer (score 2):

Use tags when searching. "[harry-potter] jobs" [search](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bharry-potter%5D%20jobs) returns only 6 hits - including  every single question I considered as a duplicate. Which is how I found them after making my comment :)

Comment: I think knowing basic search techniques helped you here. I also entered harry potter and jobs but I didn't use [].